# Import component from add-on directory

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, spring-properties, vaadin21

I am using Vaadin version 21.0.7 with Spring Boot and i want to import Paginator add-on.
I have added addon's groupId in applicaton.properties as follows: vaadin.whitelisted-packages=com.test.demo,com.vaadin.componentfactory.
The problem is that i get the following error: Paginator cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: You have to add it to the pom.xml too!

Comment: I have added the dependencies to pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Some questions you may want to update your question with answers to:

- Are you using Maven? Gradle? Something else?
- JDK version?
- Is the error a compile-time one? If so, you should add the full output to your question.

Now, for a potential solution:

Assuming you are using Maven...

(1) Make sure that Maven resolved the dependency.

Your IDE should tell you if not, or you can check your local `.m2` directory. On Windows, it is located at `${user.home}`. On macOS and most Unix/Linux distributions, it is located at `~`. Check `.m2/repositories/com/vaadin/componentfactory/paginator/<version>/` and ensure that the JARs were downloaded.

If they were not, make sure you

(a) defined the Vaadin Addons repository in your POM, e.g.,

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>

        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>

        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

(b) and defined the dependency, e.g.,

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.componentfactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>paginator</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(2) Are you using Jigsaw (Java 9+ modules)?

If you are, make sure you specified the dependency:

```java
module myModule {

  requires paginator;

}
```

Comment: @Theodore, did this help?